# Torah Commentary of R. Nissim of Marseilles

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, commentaries, internet

Is the commentary of  [R. Nissim of Marseilles](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/nissim-ben-moses-of-marseilles) on the Torah available for free online?

Comment: Is it even available for purchase?

Comment: It is! It was published by מקיצי נרדמים twenty years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His book Sefer Ma'aseh Nissim: Perush La'Torah can be viewed for free on the site of the National Library of Israel [here](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001963866/NLI).

Comment: Good find! - it is the same edition as the one on the Otzar site that I provided - but this is free access. Shkoiach!

Comment: @Dov Yep. Only downside is that the NLI doesn't let you download books.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the first 150 pages for free on the Otzar HaChochmah site [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=617869&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15999437081091082&pagenum=1) and then obviously pay for the privilege to view it further.

I hope that helps!